# Remove price from Woocommerce variable product dropdown menu

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to hidden or remove the price on each variable products inside dropdown menu on a single product page. Please see image attached below.

[image]

I believe here is the codes that needs to be edited. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
<div class="cart-form-wrapper clearfix">
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
<?php if ( ! empty( $available_variations ) ) : ?>
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php $loop = 0; foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) : $loop++; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></td>
                    <td class="value"><select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>" name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">
                        <option value=""><?php echo __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ) ?>&hellip;</option>
                        <?php
                            if ( is_array( $options ) ) {

                                if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                                    $selected_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                                } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                                    $selected_value = $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                                } else {
                                    $selected_value = '';
                                }

                                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
                                if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {

                                    $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, $name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                        if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
                                    }

                                } else {

                                    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select> <?php
                        /*if ( sizeof($attributes) == $loop )
                            echo '<a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';*/
                    ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using hook

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price',10);
```

or CSS

```
span.price
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

*Tag May be different as per your theme.

Thanks, Vee

Answer (score 0):

You find this code on your code (shared above):

```
echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
```

And replace that by this code:

```
echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
```

And this: You need find this code:

```
echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';
```

And replace that by this code:

```
echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . $option . '</option>';
```